# ¿Porqué esta función llamada: "mostrarArbol" funciona correctamente?

Tags: c++

Esta es la función que no entiendo:

```
void mostrarArbol(nodo *arbol, int cont){
    if(arbol == NULL){
        return;
    }
    else{
        mostrarArbol(arbol->der,cont+1);
        for(int i = 0; i < cont; i++){
          cout<<" ";    
        }
        cout<<arbol->dato<<endl;
        mostrarArbol(arbol->izq, cont+1);
    }
}
```

No entiendo:

- ¿Cómo llega al bucle `for` si siempre esa función se está llamando recursivamente?
- ¿Cómo se muestran los elementos del árbol si siempre esa función se está llamando recursivamente?

Si alguien me pudiera explicar como funciona esa función se los agradecería mucho.

Answer (score 4):

> ¿Cómo llega al bucle `for` si siempre esa función se está llamando recursivamente?

Lo primero es que esta función no se está llamando **siempre** recursivamente. Si eso sucediese el programa se quedaría bloqueado y no respondería ya que no sería capaz de abandonar la función recursiva.

Cuando se programa una función recursiva **siempre** debe existir un mecanismo de escape que permita detener la recursividad... en este caso la secuencia de escape la encontramos al inicio de la función:

```
if(arbol == NULL){
    return;
}
```

Es decir, esta función se ejecutará de forma recursiva **hasta** que se llegue al final de cada rama del árbol.

Nota que mientras no se cumpla esta primera condición, el programa ejecutará el `else` y ahí es donde, antes o después, se acaba ejecutando el bucle `for`

> ¿Cómo se muestran los elementos del árbol?

Esta pregunta te la podrías responder tu facilmente usando lapiz y papel.

Pero vamos, suponiendo un arbol tal que

```
  A
 / \
B   C
 \
  D
```

El programa ejecutará la siguiente secuencia:

```
mostrarArbol(A, 0)
  arbol = A
  mostrarArbol(A->der, 1)
    arbol = A->der = B
    mostrarArbol(B->der, 1)
      arbol = B->der = NULL
      return
    cout << B->dato
    mostrarArbol(B->izq, 1)
      arbol = B->izq = D
      mostrarArbol(D->der, 2)
        arbol = D->der = NULL
        return
      cout << D->dato
      mostrarArbol(D->izq, 2)
        arbol = D->izq = NULL
        return
  cout << A->dato
  mostrarArbol(A->izq, 1)
    arbol = A->izq = C
    mostrarArbol(C->der, 2)
      arbol = C->der = NULL
      return
    cout << C->dato
    mostrarArbol(C->izq, 2)
      arbol = C->izq = NULL
      return
```

Y esta secuencia debería imprimir el siguiente resultado

```
 B
  D
A
 C
```

Comment: No me has ayudado, pero de todas formas muchas gracias por esforzarte en ayudarme.

Comment: Ah, después de varios meses ya comprendo como funciona... Gracias de todas formas :]